# How can I force make to build without graphic support?

Tags: makefile, graphics, qemu, redox-os

On redox-os I have to run `make qemu` to run redox-os.
But I need to run it without graphic support, `make qemu -nographic` or `make qemu -curses` is not supported.

```
nasm -f bin -o build/harddrive.bin -D ARCH_x86_64 -ibootloader/x86_64/ bootloader/x86_64/harddrive.asm
SDL_VIDEO_X11_DGAMOUSE=0 qemu-system-x86_64 -serial mon:stdio -d cpu_reset -d guest_errors -smp 4 -m 1024 -machine q35 -net nic,model=e1000 -net user -net dump,file=build/network.pcap -device nec-usb-xhci,id=xhci -device usb-tablet,bus=xhci.0 -drive file=build/harddrive.bin,format=raw
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
gtk initialization failed
make: *** [mk/qemu.mk:32: qemu] Error 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Launch using QEMU without using KVM (Kernel Virtual Machine) nor Graphics

`make qemu kvm=no vga=no`

Just added at [Redox-os](https://github.com/redox-os/redox) by me